# Coroutines on F# that yields a value

Tags: f#, coroutine, continuations

I want to better understand continuations and coroutines.
I want to code them without using `seq` or `async` workflows.

I've found several implementations of Coroutines in `F#`
[this simple coroutines](https://gist.github.com/mrange/0cde624b7cb7b34973b2), [and this from fsharpsnippets](http://fssnip.net/7M)

My question is how can be implemented a coroutine yield that yields values to the calling coroutines, for exemple:

```
let anothercoroutine= coroutine {
    do! yieldvalue' "hello"
    do! yieldvalue' "world"
}
coroutine{
    let! a = yield' anothercoroutine
    let! b = yield' anothercoroutine
    return a + " " + b
} // it would return "hello world"
```

This is only one "hello world" example of what I want to accomplish, but I don't really need `anothercoroutine` to be a sequence generator, although it can be... This code would run side by side with other coroutines, that have been scheduled to do so.

I wanted to know if there is some implicit limitation on `F#`.
I have tried but it seems to be more difficult than expected, so I need to know if I'm just spending my time in an impossible problem.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. You don't need those snippets to execute asynchronous workflows, create a sequence generator or use a sequence inside another sequence generator. Those snippets are examples of [computation expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/computation-expressions), on which [asynchronous workflows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/asynchronous-workflows) and [query expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/query-expressions) are based

Comment: Yes, I know that, I don't need an sequence generator, I want coroutines that can send values to the other corouties and I specifically want to code it as I want to learn all the intrincicaties, . I will try to reformulate.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the point is I want to be able to code something that has a specific `custom` workflow and I want to understand how it is done. Some learning resources would be very much appreciated. I already know monads syntactic sugared by computation expressions, I understand several monads, like state and also continuation monad... but in coroutines the literature falls short

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot we could discuss in terms of how best to implement coroutines in F# and the merits of different existing implementations, but I'll just try to answer the specific question you asked here.  Specifically, why this syntax isn't used:

```
let anothercoroutine= coroutine {
    do! yieldvalue' "hello"
    do! yieldvalue' "world"
}
```

The issue here is with the meaning of `do!` in an F# computation expression.  This handy table shows us what each built-in keyword does in a computation builder:

[image: De-sugared computations]

As you can see, `do!` just calls the computation builder's `Bind` function, with a unit-accepting continuation.  Therefore, it is basically implied that that *expr* will be unit-returning, and hence not the sort of value-generating function that would be used to produce intermediate results from a coroutine.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time of answering. I modified my question as it seems that I wasn't clear. My questions is more about coroutines than computation expressions. I know how computation expression works and why and where why should use the bang version of the operators.

Comment: somehow you are right in your answe as why `do! yieldvalue "some value"` can't be used as it seems to return a value, but my question is exactly that: how to code `yieldvalue` so it takes `"some value"` pass that value to the calling coroutine and returns `unit` as a whole... mutation allowed!

Comment: `yiled'` could be called `await` so it makes more sense, and somehow `await` and `yieldvalue` should work as a whole. But I don't really understand how

Comment: @sabotero If `yieldvalue` would somehow be able to affect the state of the coroutine (and I see no other way of doing what you're suggesting), then it would have to be implemented as a `[<CustomOperation>]` on the Builder.  It could not be implemented as a function as that function would have no way to influence the state of the coroutine.

Comment: I agree with you that it should be some additional state somewhere... as I understand computations expressions they are only some syntactic sugar, so some how `yieldvalue` can be implemented so it can affects the coroutine state, and then this implementation could be behind a `[<CustomOperaion("yieldvalue">]` so it would be nicer to use it within the coroutine builder `coroutine { yieldvalue "hello" }`. I agree you could put the needed structures inside the builder, but you could also put them inside another class or module or very complex function and then use that in the builder class